# Suppressing line break in enumerate environment

Tags: lists, line-breaking, align, enumerate

I'm using the `gather` environment within the `enumerate` environment. After creating an item/before entering the `gather` environment, LaTeX adds a linebreak which I don't like.

```
\begin{enumerate}[(a)] 
\item 
    \begin{gather*}
    \text{substitution:}\\ % SHOULD BE ON THE SAME LINE AS (a)
    \begin{align*}
    \Rightarrow u(x) &= x  &\Rightarrow v'(x) &= \sin(x)&&\\
    \Rightarrow v(x) &= -\cos(x) &\Rightarrow u'(x) &= 1&&
    \end{align*}\\
    \begin{split}
    \int u(x) \cdot v'(x)  {\mathrm d}x &= u(x) \cdot v(x) - \int u'(x) \cdot v(x)  {\mathrm d}x \\
        &= x \cdot -\cos(x) - \int  -\cos(x)  {\mathrm d}x
    \end{split}\\
    \end{gather*}
\item
    \begin{gather*}
    \text{substitution:}\\
    \begin{align*}
    \Rightarrow u(x) &= (x-2)  &\Rightarrow v'(x) &= {\mathrm e}^{2x}&&\\
    \Rightarrow v(x) &= -\cos(x) &\Rightarrow u'(x) &= 1&&
    \end{align*}\\
    \begin{split}
    \int u(x) \cdot v'(x)  {\mathrm d}x &= u(x) \cdot v(x) - \int u'(x) \cdot v(x)  {\mathrm d}x \\
        &= x \cdot -\cos(x) - \int  -\cos(x)  {\mathrm d}x
    \end{split}\\   
    \end{gather*}
\end{enumerate}
```

Used packages:

```
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsthm, mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using display environments, but rather `$\begin{gathered}[t]...\end{gathered}$`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: You can still use `\displaystyle` if you need. And the -ed environments take an optional `[t]` if you want them to be aligned at the top with your enumeration.

Comment: What's the benefit of using the `gathered` environment over the `gather`environment? Apparently `begin{align}` does not work within `gathered`.

Comment: all the *ed environments are to be used inside other environments because their bounding box is the size of the content. The other environments take care of spacing around them (among other things) and therefore can not be nested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to do what you want; I'll show two, the first one is what I'd prefer.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsthm, mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
\newcommand{\euler}{\mathrm{e}}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
\item substitution:
    \begin{gather*}
    \begin{aligned}
    \Rightarrow u(x) &= x  &\Rightarrow v'(x) &= \sin(x)\\
    \Rightarrow v(x) &= -\cos(x) &\Rightarrow u'(x) &= 1
    \end{aligned}\\
    \begin{aligned}
    \int u(x) \cdot v'(x)  \diff x &= u(x) \cdot v(x) - \int u'(x) \cdot v(x) \diff x \\
        &= x \cdot -\cos(x) - \int  -\cos(x) \diff x
    \end{aligned}\\
    \end{gather*}
\item
    $\begin{gathered}[t]
    \text{substitution:}\\
    \begin{aligned}
    \Rightarrow u(x) &= (x-2)  &\Rightarrow v'(x) &= \euler^{2x}\\
    \Rightarrow v(x) &= -\cos(x) &\Rightarrow u'(x) &= 1
    \end{aligned}\\
    \begin{aligned}
    \int u(x) \cdot v'(x) \diff x &= u(x) \cdot v(x) - \int u'(x) \cdot v(x) \diff x \\
        &= x (-\cos(x)) - \int  -\cos(x) \diff x
    \end{aligned}\\
    \end{gathered}$
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Notice the definitions that free you from the burden of using `\mathrm`; by the way you should say `\mathrm{e}` rather than `{\mathrm e}`. I've also used `enumitem` that's much more powerful than `enumerate`.

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thanks (as my reputation doesn't allow me to upvote your answer). Just learned a bunch of useful things!